# How to modify {userinfoserial} via Pascal?

Tags: variables, inno-setup

If I want to modify `{userinfoserial}` variable at the end of installation (user inputs only part of the serial during the installation process).

How can I modify `{userinfoserial}` through Pascal?

I do not want to create new variable, but modify existing.

I have tried several ways, but with no luck - unfortunately `WizardUserInfoSerial` is unknown identifier where `WizardDirValue` is OK what is strange to me...

If that is not possible, then I will create new variable.

Comment: At most you can modify [`corresponding registry value`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Install.pas#L548). You cannot access the `WizardUserInfoSerial` variable, nor affect behavior of the `{userinfoserial}` constant. Also, modifying of the `UserInfoSerialEdit` edit text would user see. Btw. `WizardDirValue` is a function. You cannot modify directory with it.

Comment: OK, that is my answer. I already had my function created, so I have just pushed it. Thanks!